# android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to pass an Extra to another Activity by using intent.putExtra("result", resultBean) but I have this following error

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.tai.androidtai.domain.bean.ResultBean
```

I tried to find the solution through stackoverflow but I did not find it.

I tried to follow the same sequence between readparcel and writeparcel but it didnt change anything.

here my following code :

Activity :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        mPresenter.subscribe(this)

        displayAllUserInformation(intent.getParcelableExtra("result"))  
    }
```

Bean :

```
class ResultBean private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private var mId: Int? = null

    @SerializedName("name")
    private var mName: String? = ""

    @SerializedName("status")
    private var mStatus: String? = ""

    @SerializedName("species")
    private var mSpecies: String? = ""

    @SerializedName("gender")
    private var mGender: String? = ""

    @SerializedName("image")
    private var mImageUrl: String? = ""

    init {
        mId = parcel.readInt()
        mName = parcel.readString()
        mStatus = parcel.readString()
        mSpecies = parcel.readString()
        mGender = parcel.readString()
        mImageUrl = parcel.readString()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeInt(mId!!)
        dest.writeString(mName)
        dest.writeString(mStatus)
        dest.writeString(mSpecies)
        dest.writeString(mGender)
        dest.writeString(mImageUrl)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    fun getId(): Int {
        return mId!!
    }

    fun getName(): String {
        if (mName == null) {
            mName = ""
        }
        return mName!!
    }

    fun getStatus(): String {
        if (mStatus == null) {
            mStatus = ""
        }
        return mStatus!!
    }

    fun getSpecies(): String {
        if (mSpecies == null) {
            mSpecies = ""
        }
        return mSpecies!!
    }

    fun getGender(): String {
        if (mGender == null) {
            mGender = ""
        }
        return mGender!!
    }

    fun getImageUrl(): String {
        if (mImageUrl == null) {
            mImageUrl = ""
        }
        return mImageUrl!!
    }

    companion object {

        @SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<ResultBean> = object : Parcelable.Creator<ResultBean> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ResultBean {
                return ResultBean(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ResultBean?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but I have just to add "@JvmField" above val CREATOR

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you wrote has a problem and JVM cannot recognize it as `CREATOR` for the `Parcelable`. Instead of this:

```
companion object {

        @SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<ResultBean> = object : Parcelable.Creator<ResultBean> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ResultBean {
                return ResultBean(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ResultBean?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this syntax:

```
companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ResultBean {
                return ResultBean(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ResultBean?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in writing or reading the parcel . To solve the issue delete all the implementation or overridden methods of parcelable and then again override the method with proper implementation . You just need to press alt + enter to override the methods.